# Python : Edit a QR Code to round the corners

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I'm currently trying to make use of python to automaticly modify basic QR Codes to make the squares/pixels inside it more rounded...

Example : Transforming this

[image: Transforming this]

into this

[image: into this]

If anyone know about any library that could do the job (maybe using Pillow ?) it would be of great help.

Comment: Like [this](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18815) ? ImageMagick is simple to use from Pyhthon, so you can copy the example directly.